# best practices for updating multiple DynamoDB items

Tags: python, database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

We have inherited a DynamoDB database and have been told that a custom script is required if we want to edit/delete multiple items. ie you can't just run an easy mysql query to do this like in a relational database.

What is the most common way this is done? e.g. python script, lambda, etc.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to DynamoDB programmatically through a variety of SDKs (Javascript, .Net, Java, Go, C++, Ruby, Python, etc),in the AWS web UI console, and through the AWS command line interface (among others).  I don't think it's terribly different than other databases in that regard.

If you are just getting started, I'd start by writing a script in your preferred programming languages with one of the many SDKs available.  The [NoSQL Workbench](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html) (an app available from Amazon directly) has a useful Operation Builder that will not only help with query syntax, but will even create a script to execute the operation in Java, Javascript and Python.

The [DynamoDB API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) references the operations you can perform on DynamoDB (CRUD operations, transactions, etc).  Each API method has a section at the bottom of the page with links to examples of that method being called in each of the supported SDKs.  To mutate multiple items at once, you may want to check out the Batch operations ([BatchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html), [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html)).

I'm not entirely sure I understand the advice you were given.  DynamoDB is a noSQL database, so you cannot access it via SQL queries.  NoSQL databases can come with a steep learning curve.  I wouldn't say it's any harder than working with SQL databases, just different.

Familiarize yourself with DynamoDB data modeling, it is *very* different than data modeling in SQL databases.  When learning DynamoDB, try hard to forget everything you know about working with SQL databases.  Trying to find the SQL equivalent for something in DynamoDB consistently gives people a hard time.

I would highly recommend [The Dynamo Guide](https://www.dynamodbguide.com/) to start the learning process.  Again, it's not hard, just different than SQL databases.  The AWS docs can be a bit terse, so I found resources like The DynamoDB Guide to be a lifesaver!

Comment: The advice in this answer is very good. More specific to the question though, I'd just add that most of the 'work' is left to the programmer. You'll need to read the items first, get their IDs, then explicitly delete/edit those items using the mentioned Batch* queries. This is contrary to SQL, where you formulate a query and ask the DB to execute it. The upshot is that the DDB API is quite small, and as such it doesn't take long to master.